# Can I influence the order of directories and pages in mkdocs/mkdocs-material manually?

Tags: mkdocs, mkdocs-material

In this example, I have a book-like documentation and it has three chapters:

- Introduction
- Basic Use
- Advanced Use

These would go into separate directories (with sub-pages each ...). The file layout would look like this:

```
doc/
  advanced-use/
  basic-use/
  intro/
```

By default, mkdocs and mkdocs-material will order alphabetically, so chapters would end up in the order shown in the file layout above.

Things I know about, but would like to **avoid**:

- The [`nav` setting in `mkdocs.yml`](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/setup/setting-up-navigation/#navigation-sections): I specifically wish to avoid setting `nav`, because then I would have to manually list *every single page*.
- Including a prefix on the directory's or page's filename: If I did this and later re-arranged something, all existing links would break. I also don't want a bunch of numbers in my URLs, so ordering by filename is off the table for me.

I am looking for a way similar to jekyll's/just-the-docs' [`nav_order` variable](https://just-the-docs.com/docs/navigation-structure/#ordering-pages), which can be specified in the frontmatter metadata.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a plugin to mkdocs that does exactly what I was looking for:

[mkdocs-nav-weight](https://github.com/shu307/mkdocs-nav-weight)

You add a `weight` property to your frontmatter, and it takes care of sorting the navigation. It even keeps "previous"/"next" intact. It also deals with section index pages out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

The code to build the navigation (see [here](https://github.com/mkdocs/mkdocs/blob/master/mkdocs/structure/nav.py#L126)) suggests that there is currently no way of doing this.

I think there are two ways moving forward:

1. You build some external tool to generate the `nav` setting to list all the files the way you want them.
2. Open an Issue / PR at the mkdocs repo and built the wanted functionality into mkdocs itself.